# Number of product in multiple categories and their descendants for woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories

I want to get the number of products in multiple woocommerce categories considering this fact that each of the categories possess some subcategories.
For example:

Category with term_id of 1 have the slug of "organ" and possesses 2 subcategories( "internal" with term_id of 2 and "external" with term_id of 3)

Category with term_id of 4 have the slug of "drug-type" and possesses 2 subcategories( "pills" with term_id of 5 and "capsule" with term_id of 6)

My question is how to get the number of products that are in categories "organ" and "drug-type"?

**Edit Version 1:**

I tested the following code in my home page and it works and gave me the correct number of products in subcategories of a category with the slug of *organ*.

```
$main_product_category = get_term_by( 'slug', 'organ', 'product_cat' );
$main_product_category_id = $main_product_category->term_id;
$args = array(
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'show_option_none' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'parent' => $main_product_category_id,
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
);
$subcats = get_categories($args);
echo '<div class="quick-search-options">';
foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
    $link = get_term_link( $subcat->slug, $subcat->taxonomy );
    echo '<span>
                <a href="'. $link .'" class="btn btn-default" data-id="'.$subcat->term_id.'" role="button">'.$subcat->name.$subcat->count.'</a>
              </span>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Just to make my case more clear to you.

The diagram of my categories is like this:

[image]

The number in parenthesis is the number of products in each categories and when I run the above code it will give me correct number for each "internal" and "external" categories.

But when I test it on ajax in only gave me 0 number of products because it only searching for the products that are exactly belonging to the category it self but the weird thing is that the code is not different from the one that I tested in non ajax way.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will give you a count of all categories, including the sub-categories within a category. The subcategories products will be clubbed in the same array key as the parent category:

```
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat' );
$categories_count = array();
foreach( $product_categories as $key => $value ) {
   $category_term_id = $value->term_id;

   if ( $value->parent > 0 ) {
           $category_parent_term_id = $value->parent;
           if ( !isset( $categories_count[$category_parent_term_id] ) ) {
                   $categories_count[$category_parent_term_id] = $value->count;
           } else {
                   $categories_count[$category_parent_term_id] = $categories_count[$category_parent_term_id] + $value->count;
           }
   } else {
           if ( !isset( $categories_count[$category_term_id] ) ) {
                   $categories_count[$category_term_id] = $value->count;
           } else {
                   $categories_count[$category_term_id] = $categories_count[$category_term_id] + $value->count;       
           }
   }
}
echo 'Categories Count: <pre>';print_r($categories_count);echo '</pre>';
```

There won't be any array element present for the subcategories. The count of subcategory products would be within

Comment: @tovishlalck thanks for your quick help. but the problem is that I could not get the correct count in ajax call. I mean I have the same code in edited question version 1 but different result in ajax and default page load. Could you please help me why I am getting different result in ajax call.

Comment: @Ehsan What are you getting in the ajax call? What is the result?

Comment: @tovishlalck I added the full description by editing the question

Comment: @Ehsan The code you have pasted will give 0 for "internal" and "external" even when it's not run in ajax. The reason is that get_categories() only returns the categories that are 1-level within the provided slug, in this case "organ".

Comment: No actually this code is giving me the categories with the parent category that have the slug of 'organ' which are 'external' and 'internal' and I got the correct number of product in each subcategory of 'organ' by this method _italic_ **bold** `$subcat->count`

Comment: @Ehsan What does your Category filter on WooCommerce Products page show the count as?

Comment: @Ehsan: This is my category structure along with product count: http://screencast.com/t/NR9gPgRz1JDm . 


This is my Category filter count on WooCommerce Products page: http://screencast.com/t/zbze9ona .


Your code should the output as:
External 1, internal 1 .


The Products page filter shows the count as:
External 3, Internal 3 .


Your code is not considering the categories within Internal & External. It is only giving the count of products that have the "Internal" or "External" as category.